# Jquery not working when integrating Yii and Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, yii, cdata

Ok, so I have been trying to integrate Yii(specifically, the [Lightspeed webstore](http://www.lightspeedretail.com/ecommerce/) ([On Github](https://github.com/lightspeedretail/webstore))) and Wordpress.

I have made significant progress at [test.theoldhardwarestore.com](http://www.test.theoldhardwarestore.com) following instructions by [drumaddict](http://www.yiiframework.com/user/7096/) in his [post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/382/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-working-out-the-details/).

But I got stuck when jquery got involved.
The Lightspeed webstore used a jquery-ui dialog for the login.

On a page that has Yii's content (like the home page), it works great.
But on any page that does not have Yii content (like the [blog page](http://www.test.theoldhardwarestore.com/blog)), it does not hide the login dialog, nor does it pop up to center screen when clicking "Login".

[image]

Looking at the source, apparently Yii adds javascript with CData in it just before the dialog html.  On the pages without Yii content, this does not happen.  As I have not worked much with Yii yet, I have no idea where this is getting added.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You can check protected/views/layouts/main.php if you are using the default template usually the html header information including cdata based js file loads are set here..

Comment: Ya, there's nothing there for me...

Comment: After scouring just about everything I found what I think is the difference.http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail.  "At the end, it calls processOutput to insert scripts and dynamic contents if they are available."  What that apparently does is accept the whole html page code as a variable, parses it, and spits it back with the appropriate js. I could just call that on a wordpress page, but as far as I know there is no practical way to get the whole wp page code into a variable... is there?  There's gotta be a better way...

Comment: I use NLSClientScript to handle this sort of ajax issues.. perhaps that can help you for a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like this is the best solution, but I did get it to work.  Here is what I did:

Copied the CData generated on the yii pages and put it in a wp function:

```
function add_login_dialog()
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/a9725a95/jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>';
echo "CDATA goes here";

if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    {
        Yii::app()->controller->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
            'id'=>'LoginForm',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>Yii::t('global','Login'),
                'autoOpen'=>false,
                'modal'=>'true',
                'width'=>'350',
                'height'=>'365',
                'resizable'=>false,
                'position'=>'center',
                'draggable'=>false,
            ),
        ));

        Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('/site/_login',array('model'=>new LoginForm()));
        Yii::app()->controller->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');}
add_action('wp_footer','add_login_dialog', 100);
```

Then I also needed to add:

```
    if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
 echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/1f0ab574/css/bootstrap.css">';
 echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/a9725a95/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css">';
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/a9725a95/jquery.min.js"></script>';
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/a9725a95/jquery.yiiactiveform.js"></script>';
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/1f0ab574/js/bootstrap.js"></script>';
}
```